# How to iterate with the label by another dataframe's index?

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing, keyerror

Quite a problem to me! I've got a `df_000001` like this:

```
date          open    high   close     low       volume        amount  price_change

2000-01-04 1368.69 1407.52 1406.37 1361.21    903402300    5801550000
2000-01-05 1407.83 1433.78 1409.68 1398.32   1057998400    8653075000
2000-01-06 1406.04 1463.95 1463.94 1400.25   1348051500   10238351000
2000-01-07 1477.15 1522.83 1516.60 1477.15   3451569900   22007478000
```

And the index of it is very clear:

```
Index(['2000-01-04', '2000-01-05', '2000-01-06', '2000-01-07'])
```

While I got another df, similar to `df_000001`:

```
date        open  high  close   low       volume        amount  price_change

2010-01-04 33.62 34.27  33.50 33.42  13469261.00  549593152.00         -0.12
2010-01-05 33.76 34.97  34.69 33.72  18374008.00  760548096.00          0.93
2010-01-06 34.85 35.87  35.11 34.63  21924930.00  932180353.00          0.26
2010-01-07 35.84 36.34  34.42 34.23  21769572.00  925199040.00         -1.42
```

the index of it is:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2010-01-04', '2010-01-05', '2010-01-06', '2010-01-07'])
```

Now I wrote a for loop to iterate:

```
x1 = [df_000001.loc[si]['close'] for si in df.index]
```

It's meant to extract the `df_000001` columns with same date index of `df`.

Even though I tried hard, it just keeps running error:

```
KeyError: 'the label [2010-01-04 00:00:00] is not in the [index]'
```

How can I work this out?

Comment: do you mean extract the `rows` where the index is the same?

Comment: @Dmitry Polonskiy Specifically, the `df_000001['close']` of those `rows`.

Comment: at first glance your indexes are mismatching, convert `df_0001` to have the same index format, `df_0001.index = pd.to_datetime(df_0001.index)`

Comment: Oh, my! Didn't think that much! It really worked! Thank you! @Dmitry Polonskiy